# Selenium still shows 2.16 but pom.xml has 2.19

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, pom.xml

I'm really stuck on this one:

I'm using Maven/Eclipse and have updated my pom.xml to use Selenium 2.19 for the server 
but whenever I launch Firefox or IE via maven (mvn verify) from command line or even from eclipse, my remote runner window still shows 2.16.

I've forced snapshot updates, etc... without it working as it should.

My goal is to have 2.19 work since it's supposed to resolve the IE process from not closing ( issue 2958 ).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Check that 2.19's jars are being put on your class path. If they are not, you should look at your dependency graph to see what might be conflicting and forcing the version to stay at 2.16. 
You can then decide whether you want to exclude 2.16 from that dependency or exclude 2.16 for the whole project.